# How to switch from Ubuntu single-boot to Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I cannot install Windows from a bootable Windows USB that I create on my Ubuntu machine, I've probably used everything that could be used to make this bootable USB boot properly.

**What I have tried:**

- Woeusb
- Ventoy
- dd command
- Unebootin
- Copying ISO file content to the USB.
- Creating the bootable USB from a Windows machine.

**Results are always:**

- Blinking underscore but no booting. (for +12 hours)
- Blinking underscore for a while and Ubuntu boots instead of Windows.
- Ubuntu boots instead of Windows, ignore the bootable USB no matter the boot order.
- If I tried to get the GNU GRUB menu, Windows USB is not listed there.

**INFORMATION:**

- **PC Type:** HP Compaq 8000 elite SSF.
- **Boot Mode:** Legacy Bios.
- **Partition Table:** MBR.
- **Operating System:** Single-boot Ubuntu.

I've tried everything I came across to install Windows on this machine, and I know it's very hard to install Windows as a dual-boot after Ubuntu. So, I'm open to installing Windows only and removing Ubuntu, then reinstalling it after Windows, but the problem is that I can't even get to the installation process.

It was very easy to install Windows just with Rufus or Media Creation Tool back when I had a Windows 10 system on my machine and installed Ubuntu as a dual-boot before removing Windows. But in Linux, it's really hard, or it just might be beyond my experience in Linux.

**Note:** It's flawless when I try to boot from an Ubuntu USB.

Comment: none is this is a problem with Ubuntu :)  you are not following your hardware instructions. To boot from usb press the correct key to acces is: could be esc, f2, f8, f9. f10. 1; 5 min waiting is long enough . 2, 3 looks like a normal boot (prob. after a timeout) and 4: that will never work. if you want THAT method place ISO -on- the disk and alter grub settings to include windows ISO.

Comment: "so, I'm open to installing Windows only and removing Ubuntu, then reinstalling it after Windows" that is off topic ;-) as it does not require you to have Ubuntu for that: a bootable USB with an OS (/windows) and the boot menu from your BIOS is all. "Note: It's flawless when I try to boot from an Ubuntu USB" That should indicate a problem with the USB

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you that's really helpful, esp altering grub settings, sounds very logical, I will search about it :) Actually, I used Ventoy many times, but unfortunately, when booting from the USB it comes to the blinking underscore waiting for a few minutes and then just booting into Ubuntu again. This process has been exhausting me for months, but I keep trying, because why not :)

Comment: That blinking... I had that a lot too (I have Ventoy with 9 ISO's (1 windows 11) with windows 11 iso...a new downloaded fixed that.  and this for grub+mbr works: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453124/add-windows-10-to-grub2-bootloader  Make sure your ISO works with MBR. It will crash if it is expecting efi

Comment: @Rinzwind I can't thank you enough, you even gave me the resource to help me modify the GRUB and fix the booting issue, I'm deeply grateful for your generosity :)

Comment: make what you did an answer and accept it ;=) it will  help others